# During ML agent training, If I want to change observations, do I have to run the training from the beginning again?

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, ml-agent

During ML agent training, If I want to change observations(sensor shape, number of sensors, etc), do I have to run the training from the beginning again?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes!
A bit longer answer: Changes in anything model structure or training data related will lead to starting the training from the beginning. All the popular frameworks transfer their model structure to the GPU while building/compiling the model and there is no way of hot-swapping this during runtime.